# mysql - archiving huge database

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, database-replication, amazon-rds

I am using MySql as my database on Amazon RDS. I have read somewhere regarding archive database. My database is rapidly growing fast in terms of data so it is harming to my performance. I would like to transfer old data (3 months before) from production database and stored it into archive/some other database. But I have so many confusions regarding "foreign key" and relations between records. So, someone guide me, How to do archive my data? and what about MySql archive engine? Can I use Amazon RDS read-replica as archive database.

Comment: Take full dump using mysqldump

Comment: @Murali, mysqldump is very slow on live & huge database. meanwhile it also effects performance.

Comment: You should bring mysql instance down before taking archival from Prod.